# FFT data looks strange

Tags: signal-processing, fft

[Here is a short video of my results](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_R9bBDD7gzM)
The sound is horrible, but please bear with me.

To me, that looks a little strange. Whats with the massive spike on the first few bins? Whats the deal with the non-linearity?

I'm plotting the square root of the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts. I've tried using a logarithm on top of that, but I get a lot of movement of the baseline, that is, the spectrum doesn't stay centered in the screen.

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Are you applying a window function prior to your FFT ?

Comment: @Paul R - From the looks of the Sinc response "bumps" radiating to the sides of the main peaks, the OP appears to have used a rectangular window function.

Comment: I'm using a Blackman-Harris window

Comment: FYI: Spectra are usually shown without taking the square root (ie just the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary part), since that corresponds to energy. Also if you're taking the log, the square root just becomes a factor of 0.5.

Answer (score 5):

Actually your posted FFT results looks fairly normal.

1. You have a huge DC offset which affects the first few bins of the FFT result.
2. You also have harmonics or harmonic distortion in your time-domain signal creating the train of overtones you see above your sine-wave frequency sweep peak in the FFT result.
3. You have aliasing, possibly from a lack of sufficient low pass filtering before sampling, causing these overtones to wrap completely across or around the frequency response from the complex conjugate peak on the other side of the FFT result, and thus appear to be moving the other direction.
4. Since your frequency sweep produces frequencies that are not at the FFT bin centers, and you are not using any kind of "flat-top" window, this will cause the slight Sinc response magnitude scalloping you are seeing in the main signal peak.
5. Since you appear to have used a rectangular window, you have further Sinc response magnitude "bumps" radiating to the side from you main peak whenever a frequency peak isn't at an FFT bin center.  Sometimes called "spectral leakage".

Comment: So with what I have now, it would be OK to check certain bins to see if I have treble tones or bass tones?

Comment: Audio spectrum tones?  Maybe.  Musical pitch tones?  Probably not.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but how could I improve my results? I'm looking into implementing a low pass filter, but beyond that, what could you suggest? I would like to minimize the effect of the DC component on my first few bins to make low frequencies more clearly visible. Would a different window help?

Comment: @drunkmonkey - A low pass filter is the opposite of what you need to remove a DC component; better would a high pass filter, or a DC blocker, or just subtract the average of the entire window before the FFT.  But that should be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The first bin is DC.  If your sample window has a DC bias (in other words it has an average that's not 0) then there will be a lot of energy in the DC bin.  This could be as simple as passing in unsigned data centered around 2^{n-1} rather than signed data centered around 0.

I'm not sure what you mean by "nonlinearity" from your text or your video.

Comment: What I mean is, the high end of the spectrum is spread across more than half of my "oscilloscope," and the mid-range to very low frequencies are only in the first third. I'm curious why my spike does not move at a constant rate down my scope.

Comment: @drunkmonkey - Are you sweeping the frequency by a ratio or an absolute delta f over time?

Comment: Thats a good point. I'm not certain, actually. I found the mp3 on the internet and I just assume that it would've been a delta over time.